# How to disable defaultLookAndFeel object in devexpress

Tags: c#

Here is a problem with me that i had used the `defaultlookandfeel`
object from tools in my project (Dev Express Tools) but something went wrong with this now i want to remove this object from my project.
i worked a lot but found nothing.
if anyone has an idea related to `defaultLooknAndFeel` object then feel free to guide me.

Thanks a lot

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M37CJ.png)